# How to setup scala sbt project for nd4j and deeplearning4j

Tags: scala, sbt, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I want to run the LSTM code from [deeplearning4j examples](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/tree/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/recurrent/character) in my own sbt project using scala. My setup is Ubuntu 14.04, sbt 0.13, Oracle Java 8, nd4j version 0.5.0, scala 2.11.8. My approach can be found in my git [repo](https://github.com/arzt/deeplearning-example). Feel free to clone it.
On runtime I get the following [warnings and errors](https://github.com/arzt/deeplearning-example/blob/master/stack-trace.txt). How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you have all necessary dependencies? The error says that something is missing on the classpath.

Comment: I followed the instructions on http://nd4j.org/getstarted.html, but could not find a setup that works solely with SBT. The original deeplearning4j example project is working. But it uses Maven. Analyzing the dependencies on both projects using IntelliJ did not show any differences.

Comment: See this -> https://github.com/kogecoo/dl4j-examples-scala

Comment: Hi, If you don't see it under github.com/deeplearning4j don't trust what you see there. Often times that stuff is unmaintained and HUGELY out of date

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the nd4s build.sbt:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4s/blob/master/build.sbt

Comment: It uses the local maven repo of the user.

Comment: The dependencies declarations still apply though.

Comment: Cloning https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4s and following installation instructions results in a sbt.ResolveException for 'nd4j-native' package jar.

Comment: You should be using nd4j-native-platform for the artifact id (btw if you're still having problems the live chat suggested above will be easier for both of us) Try following the nd4j.org/getstarted.html if this isn't working Most of our users have had it work.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly due to a bug in SBT some internal variables are currently not resolved causing the resolution of the dependency 'nd4j-native-package' to fail. As a workaround you can use the following dependency declaration for nd4j:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.nd4j" % "nd4j-native" % "0.5.0" classifier "$platform",
  "org.nd4j" % "nd4j-native" % "0.5.0"
)
```

For a comprehensive list which platform strings are supported see http://nd4j.org/dependencies.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please update the link http://nd4j.org/dependencies.html? It is redirecting to https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/nd4j-overview and I can't find a word about platform strings there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Coursier plugin enabled in sbt and see errors like:

```
coursier.ResolutionException: 1 not found
  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.5.0/nd4j-native-0.5.0-${os.name}-${os.arch}.${project.packaging}
[error] (*:update) coursier.ResolutionException: 1 not found
[error]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.5.0/nd4j-native-0.5.0-${os.name}-${os.arch}.${project.packaging}
```

You'll want to disable it or get a version that contains the fix for [alexarchambault/coursier#341](https://github.com/alexarchambault/coursier/issues/341)

Answer (score -1):

Can you join the Deeplearning4j/ND4J community on Gitter? Someone will answer your questions there... https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j